# event prevent default in ReactJS when click on <a>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This code doesn't work.

`<a href="/any/url" target="_blank" onClick={ e => e.preventDefault() }>`

If I click on the link, an event triggers anyways. And I have no idea why.

I've looked through dozen of the similar questions but couldn't find the answer.

Here is [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html). But it also doesn't work in this way.

Comment: It's not possible, posted code guarantied to prevent default action. Maybe you misunderstand or confuse something. Explain what happens and what *you think* should happen.

Comment: I've thought so. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by event triggers anyways? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Explain "it doesn't work". What you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to do not go to link.

Comment: I did a fiddle with your code and apparently it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/yk2e9ku5/4/. The link is not being triggered. Can you post your whole component code (or the main parts)?

Comment: @dfsq, you're right, waiting for more details

Comment: Q any console error?

Comment: @mrlew I created a separated component in the root of my application. Just <a> tag with `e.preventDefault()`. Nothing more. But it doesn't work like in your fiddle. 

@BrunoBG no errors, no messages, no any information) it just triggers but it hasn't to.